# C# WebClient ошибка при приёме

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient

Я хочу распарсить сайт,но ловлю вот такую ошибку:

SocketException: Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера

Перепробовал много разных User-Agent, но ничего не выходит. Прошу помогите.
Вот код:

```
        WebClient w = new WebClient();
        
        w.Headers.Add(
            HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent,
            "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.6; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; InfoPath.2; SLCC1;.NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152;.NET CLR 3.5.30729;.NET CLR 2.0.50727) 3gpp-gba UNTRUSTED/1.0");

        
        string page = w.DownloadString(textBox1.Text);
        foreach (Match i in Regex.Matches(page, textBox2.Text)) {
            richTextBox1.Text += i.ToString() + "\n";
        }
```

Comment: Версии windows и .net какие?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.8.4360.0 и Windows 10.

Comment: Попробуйте .NET 5, если не заработает, надо сравнивать траф браузера и ваш траф, заголовки которые могут влиять могут быть разные. Все зависит именно от сервера, на котором сайт.